# how to use typedef in class definition and implementation

Tags: c++

I have a class definition:

```
using namespace std;

class DataBase
{
private:
    ....
    typedef DataBase::vector<Object> objectVector;
    typedef DataBase::map<ObjectType, objectVector> objectMap;
    objectMap objects;
    ....

};
```

and an implementation file:

```
....

void DataBase::createObject(const ObjectType type, ifstream& strm)
{
  switch(type)
  {
     case Fiction:
          objectVector fic = objects[Fiction];  //complains about unknown type
          break;
      ....
}

....
```

I get the error `unknown type name 'objectVector'`. I can´t get the row with the complaint right. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
The error of mine was not including the header . So for you guys with similar errors check that you have included all the needed types for you typedef.

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: Those typedefs should almost certainly not contain DataBase::. Ie: typedef vector<Object> objectVector; would be more correct.

Comment: @patriques `Database::vector` means a nested class `vector` (or a typedef `vector` that you have defined within `....`. Is that really what you mean (as opposed to `std::vector`)? If so please show the definitions of `Database::vector` and `Database::map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

The compiler does for some reason not find a the declaration of `objectVector`. 
If he would have found a declaration that is not a definition (like a forward declaration of a class) he would complain about the fact that you try to define an object of incomplete type.

So check whether you've included all header files, check for typos and so on.

Comment: The Error was not including header file <vector>. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no class/type called `DataBase::vector` or `DataBase::map`.

Try.

```
class DataBase
{
private:
    ....
    typedef std::vector<Object> objectVector;
    typedef std::map<ObjectType, objectVector> objectMap;
    objectMap objects;
    ....

};
```